# How to load pandas DataFrame objects as separate tables using Loader?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of CSV files in the `test` folder. I load them into `table` object as follows:

```
from load_csv import Loader
tables = Loader("C://myfolder")
```

This is the hierarchy in `myfolder`:

```
myfolder
 - TestTable1.csv
 - TestTable2.csv
 - TestTable3.csv
```

Then I can query each CSV file as a separate table as follows:

```
tables.TestTable1\
    .query("ID not in [1, 2, 3]")\
    .groupby('ID')\
    .agg('sum')
```

How can I create the same `tables` using a list of pandas DataFrame objects in memory instead of `Loader("C://myfolder")`?

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
```

**UPDATE:**

Please notice that I load pandas DataFrames from Azure Blob Storage. Therfore the solution should consider `[df1, df2, df3]` as a starting point. I cannot use `C://myfolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a class.

```
class TableLoader(object):

    def __init__(self, path_to_csvs):
        self.path_to_csvs = path_to_csvs
        self.set_objects()

    def set_objects(self):
        for file in os.listdir(self.path_to_csvs):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                filename = file[:-4]
                f = pd.read_csv(file)
                setattr(self, filename, f)

tables = TableLoader(r'C:/Users/Jarad/Downloads/csv_directory')
```

The setattr part will set each CSV file as an attribute of the class so you can use dot notation to access the dataframes.

---

**Edit:** Possible solution for passing dataframes that already exist.

```
class DfLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
        self.set_dfs()
    def set_dfs(self):
        for i,arg in enumerate(self.args):
            name = 'df{}'.format(i)
            setattr(self, name, arg)

table = DfLoader(df1, df2, df3)
```

It's not clear what you would name them internally within the class.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid. I want to be able to do `TableLoader([df1,df2,df3])` instead of passing a path to a local folder.

Comment: I load pandas DataFrames in a different way (from Azure Blob Storage). Therefore I cannot do `C:/Users...`

Comment: How could I adjust your solution to my case? I think that it might almost fit. Thanks.

Comment: `TableLoader([df1,df2,df3])` .. what would the dfs be in this case? DataFrame objects already?

Comment: Yes, each `dfx` would be a DataFrame object.

Comment: So then the only point of your question would be to use dot notation to access multiple dataframes from one tables object? Since you already have multiple dataframe objects in memory, you just want them to live under one variable and access them through that one variable. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, right. My goal is to be able to apply the code that I posted in my question: `tables.TableTest1.query(…)...`